# How to insert multiple values in table using subquery in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have created two new tables `TYPE` and `OPERATION`-

`TYPE` table has the following columns

```
TYPE
(TYPE_ID : integer, with sequence
TYPE_NAME : String
BASE_ID : 
)
```

The default values for TYPE_NAME are `(Type1, Type2, Unknown)` which needs to be added for every `BASE_ID` which is 68 rows in the `BASE` table
So there need to be 3 entries for every `BASE_ID` in the `TYPE` table

`OPERATION` table has the following columns

```
OPERATION
(OPERATION_ID : integer, with sequence
OPERATION_NAME : String
BASE_ID : 
)
```

The default values for OPERATION_NAME are `(Operation1, Operation2, Unknown)` which needs to be added for every `BASE_ID` which is 68 rows in the `BASE` table
So there need to be 3 entries for every `BASE_ID` in the `OPERATION` table

Can someone please help me with a query so that I can perform this process of multiple entry with ease.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger that inserts the value for column TYPE_ID.

```sql
create trigger TYPE_INS
before insert on TYPE
for each row
when (new.TYPE_ID is null)
begin
  :new.TYPE_ID := TYPE_SEQ.nextval;
end;
```

Then you don't need the TYPE_ID column in the INSERT statement, which allows you to do...

```sql
insert into TYPE (TYPE_NAME, BASE_ID)
select 'Type1', BASE_ID
  from BASE
union
select 'Type2', BASE_ID
  from BASE
union
select 'Unknown', BASE_ID
  from BASE
```

Comment: I am trying to execute it but I get the following error on Oracle 
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here
02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"
*Cause:    The specified sequence number (CURRVAL or NEXTVAL) is inappropriate
           here in the statement.
*Action:   Remove the sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

Had to individually add query like this

```
INSERT INTO TYPE(TYPE_ID, TYPE_NAME, BASE_ID) (
select TYPE_SEQ.nextval, 'Type 1', ID_BASE FROM BASE);

INSERT INTO TYPE(TYPE_ID, TYPE_NAME, BASE_ID) (
select TYPE_SEQ.nextval, 'Type 2', ID_BASE FROM BASE);

INSERT INTO TYPE(TYPE_ID, TYPE_NAME, BASE_ID) (
select TYPE_SEQ.nextval, 'Unknown', ID_BASE FROM BASE);
```

Answer (score 0):

CTE with cross join might help. Here's how.

Creating tables and a sequence first; my `base` table contains only 3 rows (as opposed to your 68 rows; just for simplicity. You don't have to create the `base` table as you already have it):

```
SQL> create table base as
  2    select 1 base_id from dual union all
  3    select 2 base_id from dual union all
  4    select 3 base_id from dual;

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seqankit;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table type (type_id number, type_name varchar2(20), base_id number);

Table created.

SQL> create table operation (operation_id number, operation_name varchar2(20), base_id number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

Inserting into `type` and `operation` tables:

```
SQL> insert into type (type_id, type_name, base_id)
  2  with names (type_name) as
  3    (select 'type1' from dual union all
  4     select 'type2' from dual union all
  5     select 'unknown' from dual
  6    )
  7  select seqankit.nextval, n.type_name, b.base_id
  8  from names n cross join base b;

9 rows created.

SQL> insert into operation (operation_id, operation_name, base_id)
  2  with names (operation_name) as
  3    (select 'operation1' from dual union all
  4     select 'operation2' from dual union all
  5     select 'unknown'    from dual
  6    )
  7  select seqankit.nextval, n.operation_name, b.base_id
  8  from names n cross join base b;

9 rows created.

SQL>
```

What's the result?

```
SQL> select * from type order by base_id, type_name;

   TYPE_ID TYPE_NAME               BASE_ID
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 type1                         1
         4 type2                         1
         7 unknown                       1
         2 type1                         2
         5 type2                         2
         8 unknown                       2
         3 type1                         3
         6 type2                         3
         9 unknown                       3

9 rows selected.

SQL> select * from operation order by base_id, operation_name;

OPERATION_ID OPERATION_NAME          BASE_ID
------------ -------------------- ----------
          10 operation1                    1
          13 operation2                    1
          16 unknown                       1
          11 operation1                    2
          14 operation2                    2
          17 unknown                       2
          12 operation1                    3
          15 operation2                    3
          18 unknown                       3

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Looks OK to me.